# Minified CSS file doesn't update when I modify the normal css file - Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am having problem on my Wordpress to save changes on module.css file.
It appears that I have a minified file : module.min.css which comes with the theme.

Each times I make a change it the module.css file, it doesn't change it on my website page. I check with google inspector, and the minified file is loaded, obvioulsy, without my changes.

My website page : https://dermelia.fr/epilation-laser-un-acte-medical/

I saw it could be a caching problem, then I tried to purge cache, I use WP Rocket plugin and Clouflare. I cleaned the cache on both Clouflare and my website, still nothing...

I would like to add just a border-top on my ".widget ul li { " class

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 3):

Hi Changing in your css files will not reflect in your min.css files you have to update it.
To updated the changes use,
**grunt uglify
grunt cssmin**

if you want to update html use,
**grunt htmlmin**

If you don't have grunt please install it.

Answer (score 0):

If `module.min.css` is generated at run time by some plugin like [autoptimize](https://wordpress.org/plugins/autoptimize/), it is most probably cache-related problem.

However, in your case, the theme most probably simply has two options (minified & not minified CSS) & you have chosen to use minified version to improve performance.

In this case, CSS files are completely independent & change in 1 file, will not affect another in any way.

You have two options:

1. Make changes in not-minified CSS file and then minify it on your own. Finally update both files.
2. Switch to use not-minified version & install something like previously mentioned [autoptimize](https://wordpress.org/plugins/autoptimize/) to calculate minified files at runtime.

Please note, that in both cases you would be better off by not modifying original theme files & creating [a child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) instead.

Otherwise, all your changes will be lost once the theme will be updated.